# Grassman variable and Grassmannian?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, grassmannian, noncommutative-geometry, superalgebra

- [Grassman variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) are anticommuting number or supernumber, is an element of the exterior algebra over the complex numbers.
- [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $Gr(k, V)$ is a space that parameterizes all $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of the $n$-dimensional vector space V.

Are there relations between the two concepts: Grassman variables and Grassmannian?

Comment: You can embed the Grassmannian into the projective space of an exterior power; this is called the Plucker embedding: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding

Comment: many thanks @Qiaochu Yuan!

Comment: Is that related to Grassman variables too?

Comment: An exterior power is part of an exterior algebra.

Comment: Thanks --- is is that how Grassmann invented or discovered Grassman variable and Grassmannian at the same time? if so Why not calling Grassmann embedding instead of Plucker embedding? ;p

Comment: I don’t know anything about the history unfortunately.